# How can I see the location where a push came from?

Tags: git

If I push from a working repo to a bare repo, what cammand can I use to see only the location of the repo that pushed?

For example, if I push from /some/path/myRepo to /some/other/path/anotherRepo, what command will tell me that the push came from "/some/path/myRepo" if my current working directory is /some/other/path/anotherRepo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can only tell who pushed it and not from where it was pushed.

If you were having, for example, http access to your repo through Apache, you can track where the push is coming from etc., but there is not a way to do that with git and definitely not when pushing to repos in local path.